# Mapbox Studio: Make a text-name entry with infos from different columns

Tags: label, mapbox, tilemill

I have map box studio 0.2.7 for mac. I need to make a label combining infos from 2 different columns, for example the Name and the Tel Number of a vendor.

This is my code so far:

```
#Vendors{
  line-width: 1;
  line-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  polygon-fill: #ffff00; 
  text-name: "[VendorName]";
  text-face-name: 'Arial Unicode MS Regular';
  //text-name:[TEL_Local];
}
```

Setting `text-name` again will overwrite the old entry, so I was wondering if there is something like this:

```
text-name: "[VendorName] & [TEL_Local]";
```

or

```
text-name: "[VendorName + TEL_Local]";
```

Both don't work, but You get the idea of what I need. How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
text-name: [VendorName] + [TEL_Local];
```

This works for me in Mapbox Studio:
[image]